# Start PHP server within PHP

Tags: php, server

How can you start a php server within a php script? For example in a test setup I need to start a server on a php file to mock an api call.

Something like??

```
 shell_exec('php -S localhost:5000 ' . __DIR__ . '/mockserver.php');
```

If this is the right way, how can I stop the process?

Comment: "I need to start a server on a php file to mock an api call." smell like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Are you sure you are asking the right question?

Comment: I have a class that calls an api with guzzle and I'm trying to test this class. This class takes the host in the ctor for guzzle to hit so to test I created a php file to handle the request. For the test and simply pass localhost into the class and start a php server on the php file that handles the request for the test.

Comment: Why don't you just mock out guzzle? You don't need to test guzzle right?

Comment: That is a good point

Answer (score 0):

It technically would be possible, have a look at [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and [`proc_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php).

Of course these need to be enabled in your PHP install as they open a huge security hole.

Answer (score 0):

create an bash file with:

```
#!/bin/bash
procid=$( pgrep phpmockserver )
#ignore the echo, just to output the number of the process
#echo "$procid"
kill -9 $procid
```

create a simbolic link of php:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/phpmockserver
```

when you need to stop the process, simply call the bash file with:

```
shell_exec('bash <path to bash file>');
```

dont forget to run the php server with:

```
shell_exec('phpmockserver -S localhost:5000 ' . __DIR__ . '/mockserver.php');
```

otherwise this "hack" wont work